# Резервное копирование. Мобильная разработка

Tags: android, android-studio, резервное-копирование, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Делаю мобильное приложение. Пользователь может туда вносить свои данные. Возник вопрос, что если пользователь поменяет телефон, то необходимо, чтобы его данные сохранились. Решила, что резервное копирование, а затем, и последующее восстановление данных - самый оптимальный вариант (если учесть еще факт, что приложение оффлайн). Так вот, подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно устроить. Ну или, скиньте ссыло4ку где можно прочитать. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Поднять свой сервер и сохранять данные туда или воспользоваться Firebase'ом

Comment: а нельзя с помощью локального резервного копирования?

Comment: Ну сохранили вы локально. Что дальше? Как вы достанете оттуда данные, если пользователь сменит аппарат???

Comment: ну, с помощью того же восстановления: загрузить этот файл там...

Comment: Ну тогда все данные сохраняем в бд, пользователь переносит файл бд на новый аппарат, там считываем их. Если есть и медиафайлы, то архивируем вместе с бд. Пользователь переносит архив на новый аппарат, там разархивируем и восстанавливаем данные